# Typeahead.js: event for remote data being fetched on initialise?

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I have a remote Bloodhound source for a Typeahead input. The remote source returns a list of books and their publication dates. The Typeahead input allows the user to type a title and then autocompletes to include the date as well, using the remote data.

I want to set the initial value of the input using just a book title (I don't know the publication date at that point), and then have the value update to the date as well. This is working ok with the code I have.

However, I would like to listen for the event for when the value updates to include the data. This is so that I can set the date as an attribute elsewhere in the page.

How can I listen for the point when the remote data is fetched and the date is known?

Here is my code:

```
var books = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=quilting',
    transform: function(response) {
      return response.items;
    }
  }
});
books.initialize();

$('input').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: function(suggestion) {
    return suggestion.volumeInfo.title + ' (' + suggestion.volumeInfo.publishedDate + ')';
  },
  source: books.ttAdapter()
});

$('input').typeahead('val', 'Your First Quilt Book');

// Question: 
// When the 1997 date of this book is known, set it elsewhere in the page?
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2Cres/50/

I've tried listening for `displayKey` but it seems to fire multiple times on first load.